# facebook payment tester gets error code 1353028

Tags: facebook, facebook-payment-dialog

trying to implement the new Facebook local currencies, and I keep getting error code 1353028 if I set a user as a payment tester. if I remove the user from the payment user the payment dialog will open correctly.

the app is in sandbox mode, and the mentioned user has a "tester" role.
I also tried disabling sandbox and removing the user from being a tester, just leave him as a payment tester, but still not working.

what else remains to try? anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

and why on earth would Facebook prevent app admin/developers from being also payment testers??

Answer (score 0):

well, I tried it again the day after, without changing anything, and there it is working properly, showing me the payment dialog with 2 options (success, failure) just like in Facebook's tutorial...

so for anyone having the same issue, try leaving it for a night...